# How to parse JSON response in filemaker script

Tags: json, xml, filemaker

I am calling a rest api through filemaker script 'insert from url' . I am getting an xml response in browser but json response in my filemaker record. How is this happening :O.

Anyway I would like to parse this json response in filemaker. How can i accomplish that?

[here](https://cloud-stage.dpd.com/api/v1/setOrder) is the api

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try **importing** directly from the HTTP request, using a custom XSLT stylesheet to transform the response to FileMaker's FMPXMLRESULT grammar. -- P.S. Why don't you provide a URL that produces some data, instead of an error.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks its really helpfull

Comment: Most probably the default Content Type for the API is set to JSON. You would need to change header  of your request to Content-Type: application/xml, which is impossible without a plugin. @michael.hor257k, XML import does not necessary changes the content-type of the request.

Comment: @NicolaiKant I am not going to speculate about the API's behavior. My point is that importing XML is much easier and more robust that trying to parse JSON using FileMaker text functions.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The point I am making is that the url you are requesting with Import XML might still return JSON, which you will not be able to process with XSLT

Comment: @NicolaiKant Then the question becomes how to make the API return XML (which it apparently can). This question has nothing to do with FileMaker, and OP has provided us with no resources to try and answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several plugins that can help you handle JSON: BaseElements, bBox, MBS and probably others.

The FileMaker Community discussion on [Script from FM to pull and parse a JSON file](https://community.filemaker.com/thread/165934) has links to these, as well as some Custom Functions for native parsing.